# Is there a way to transfer the output value from Python to the cell of excel one by one using openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I learned a little about python and openpyxl, but I want to use these.

Is there a way to put the string(result below) output from python into each cell of excel using openpyxl as follows...? Thank you!

```
string_pool = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

def array_string(names):
    result = ""
    for i in range(30):
        i += 1
        result += random.choice(string_pool)
    print(result)
    return result

for name in names:
    array_string(name)


result-> DDAABACBACDCCBBCCACDACAADACDBD
         CABDDCCBCCAADCCCDCADBCCDDBAACB
         DBCDCDBCABBDCABBADBCCDADCDDBCB
```

Comment: I think the simple answer is yes. Please be more specific about where you want the values and try the openpyxl tutorial.

Comment: I want to put the data on excel like this.
D(A1 cell) D(B1 cell) A(C1 cell) A(D1 cell) B(E1 cell)
C(A2 cell) A(B2 cell) B(C2 cell) D(D2 cell) D(E2 cell)
D(A3 cell) B(B3 cell) C(C3 cell) D(D3 cell) C(E3 cell)